# Localization just from IMU data?

Tags: localization, imu, navigation, octomap, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a solution to localize my robot just from IMU data.
The problem is, I have some Velodyne 3D scans and IMU data saved to a Bag file and I need to make an Octomap or some other 3D reconstruction method to visualize my data.

I tested the `laser_scan_matcher` and the `pointcloud_to_laserscan` package but the first throws an error `Invalid number of rays: 62112` and the second one just outputs something like a straight line that doesn't change. So both are not capable of processing the huge amount of Velodyne data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61758/localization-just-from-imu-data?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) on 2017-10-09**:
I got both the laser_scan_matcher and the pointcloud_to_laserscan package working with the VLP-16 LiDAR, you have to change some parameters for both to get them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what a Velodyne is, but I know you can't hope to use just the IMU unless it's a **VERY** precise one. For a more indepth discussion of this problem see my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/59121/reading-from-an-imu-single-axis/).

You could try to augment the IMU by using a Kalman with both the IMU data and the odometry data.

And you could also give the [Velodyne stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/velodyne) a try.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-04-30**:
Thanks for your answer. Velodyne is a very precise 3D LIDAR Scanner with I think about 1million points per second. But there seems to be no package to use this point cloud for localization. The problem is I had a 2D Laser scanner mounted on my robot also, but the data was not recorded right...

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-04-30**:
And I need a way to get a 3D reconstruction of the Velodyne data, and I only have a thermal cam image, Kinect RGB Image ( depth image also got lost somehow) and an omnidirectional image...